# I am getting this Error: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@FirstName' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
private void txtName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Search_Student",
        DBConnection.GetConnection());
    DA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                    
    DA.SelectCommand.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = (txtName.Text).Trim();

    DataTable DA1 = new DataTable();
    DA.Fill(DA1);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DA1;
}
```

Comment: Just curious. Is there a reason you aren't using something like EntityFramework?

Answer (score 2):

you have to  Add  parameter first before assign value of parameter

```
SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Search_Student",
        DBConnection.GetConnection());
    DA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                    


     SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
     param.ParameterName = "@FirstName";
      param.Value  = txtName.Text;


    DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

    DataTable DA1 = new DataTable();
    DA.Fill(DA1);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DA1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you code as, You have not added parameter to command parameter collection.

```
DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtName.Text.Trim());
```

Above perform both

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", txtName.Text.Trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
var paramFName = e.Command.CreateParameter("@FirstName", (txtName.Text).Trim());
e.Command.Parameters.Add(paramFName);
```